# Over-use of require() in node.js, mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, design-patterns, architecture, mongoose

I'm new to Node.js, but quite like the module system and `require()`. 
That being said, coming from a C background, it makes me uneasy seeing the same module being `require()`'d everywhere. All in all, it leads me to some design choices that deviate from how things are done in C. For example:

- Should I `require()` mongoose in *every* file that defines a mongoose model? Or inject a mongoose instance into each file that defines a model.
- Should I `require()` my mongoose models in every module that needs them? Or have a model provider that is passed around and used to provide these models.

Ect. For someone who uses dependency injection a lot - my gut C feeling is telling me to `require()` a module only once, and pass it around as needed. However, after looking at some open-source stuff, this doesn't seem to be Node way of things. `require()` does make things super easy..

Does it hurt to overuse this mechanism?

Comment: You're probably not going to find a universal truth for this. Requiring a module more than once won't usually be harmful. It's typically done to avoid [Cycles](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles). But, DI is certainly possible with Node.js. It just won't be as common in most resources because it's generally less direct, which can add challenges in documenting. But, I believe you might find decent examples in [`npm`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) and [`npm-www`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www).

Comment: Actually, `require` works better in this aspect, in that it will cache, while as in a lot of C preprocessors(except for `clang`'s, i think), an `#include` will go ahead and include and not check or cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`require()` caches modules when you use it. When you see the same file or module required everywhere it's only being loaded once, and the stored `module.exports` is being passed around instead. This means that you can use `require` everywhere and not worry about performance and memory issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm aware the node caches modules; but my question isn't necessarily a *performance* question, but rather about *design*. Being able to `require()` any module anywhere, regardless if it having any business having access to said module, seems odd (from a C background)

Comment: Where's the difference compared to #include some header all over the place in C?

Comment: @Krumelur besides the caching cptroot mentioned - not much. The difference is that in C, it's common practice to *not* have too many places #include a file, where as in node it seems common to liberally`require()` a module whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

As cptroot states requiring a module everywhere you need it instead of passing it around as an argument is safe to do and is also much easier. However, you should view any require call as a hardcoded dependency which you can't change easily. E.g. if you want to mock a module for testing these hardcoded dependencies will hurt.

So passing a module instance around as an argument instead of just requiring it again and again reduces the amount of hardcoded dependencies because you inject this dependency now. E.g. in your tests you will benefit from easily injecting a mock instead.

If you go down this road you will want to use a dependency injection container that helps you injecting all your dependencies and get rid of all hardcoded require calls. To choose a dependency injection container appropriate for your project you should read this [excellent article](http://www.mariocasciaro.me/dependency-injection-in-node-js-and-other-architectural-patterns). Also check out [Fire Up!](https://github.com/analog-nico/fire-up) which I implemented.